# Union-like symbol meaning

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

On [axiom of choice](https://brilliant.org/wiki/axiom-of-choice/) page I have encountered this formula:

[image]

What does U-like symbol there means? It resembles [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_union) symbol, but union symbol should be used with two sets on the left and on the right. Then what does this symbol mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a union symbol. It is the union of all sets $S_i$, as $i$ ranges over all elements of the index set $I$.

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i =\Bigl\{x\,\Bigm|\, \text{there exists }i\in I\text{ such that }x\in S_i\Bigr\}.$$

The symbol you describe is a special case,
$$A_1\cup A_2 = \bigcup_{i\in\{1,2\}} A_i.$$

Answer (score 2):

It *is* the union symbol. In this context, it is the union of all sets $S_i$, with $i\in I$.

Answer (score 2):

This symbol is write the summation symbol, and represents a shorthand for union of many sets. In particular,
$$\bigcup_{i=0}^nA_i = A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots A_n$$

In your case, that means the union of all sets $S_i$ where $i$ is the element of $\mathcal I$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the union of several sets. For example, if $\mathcal{I} = \{1,2,3\}$ then it would indicate $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3$.